# How to prevent network drives from being automatically remapped

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I am in an enterprise environment using Windows XP.  There's a long delay between after I login and when the desktop shows up, usually around 5 minutes of waiting.  I suspect a significant part of the delay is the computer trying to connect to the 10 or so network drives, of which I only need 2.  I've disconnected the other 8 unnecessary network drives several times, but whenever the computer reboots, it puts those drives back.  Perhaps the company has deployed a login script that automatically maps these drives - I'm not sure.  Nevertheless, I would like to know if there is a good way to PREVENT the unwanted network drives from being remapped?

Comment: It sounds to me like you're not part of the sysadmin team. You should contact contact your help desk, raise a ticket and get it solved that way.

Answer (score 1):

In a proper environment, mapping drives should not take much time at all. In my experience, most logon delays are caused by the system waiting for your user profile to download. The profile includes your settings/preferences as well as anything you have stored on your Desktop, in your "My Pictures", "My Documents", etc. If you have a mapped drive that is supposed to contain user files, store as much as you can there and as little as you can actually in your profile.

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows_profile#Profile_contents

Other delays can be caused by network timeouts (possibly from mounts that no longer exist) and a large number of applications starting at logon.

Answer (score 0):

Remove yourself from the user permission on these drives.

Assuming you don't have the credentials to do this yourself, ask someone from IT. Without permission, it will just skip and move on.

Comment: if my permission is removed from these drives, can I still access them by going to their full paths ("\\...")?  I still want to be able to access them, just not automatically remapped at login time.

Comment: If your permission is removed you will NOT be able to access them by their full paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `net use /persistent:no` to try and prevent re-mapping remembered maps, but the maps may well be due to a login script.

As others have pointed out, the delay is probably not due to the drive mappings though.